# Error: You don't have permission to access that port

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, permissions, port

I am using the ubuntu server and want to deploy Django project in AWS using ec2, and it requires me to use port 80 to access its HTTP how do I solve this problem?
I heard from other people `using sudo` and enabling env but this error is all I got

> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Please help I really need help

Comment: do you get this error when you use `sudo` or do you always get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting with sudo because of the path, I am assuming you must be using `virtualenv` or any other tool for managing the python version and corresponding dependencies.

You can actually change the port where you `default runserver`

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:<your_port>
```

[django change default runserver port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23639676/2246345)

The port numbers from 1 to 1023 are restricted for `root user` only and we can not assign those ports without having root access. If you actually want to start the server on port 80, there are some.

[How to bind to port number less than 1024 with non root access?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bind-port-number-less-1024-non-root-access/)

```sh
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /path/to/binary
```

OR

```sh
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 777 /etc/authbind/byport/80

authbind --deep /path/to/binary command line args
```