# Why the app doesn't run locally with port mapping- docker

Tags: docker

My problem is when I run my application on a container and map a port, the app does not run on my local machine.

---

I use ubuntu and here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.13-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /app/
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN apk add -u zlib-dev jpeg-dev gcc musl-dev
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
ENV API_URL='http://my_api.com'
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "8000"]
```

when I run the image with the command bellow django app starts in the container.

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 dj-test
```

I say that because when I run a shell in this container

```
docker exec -it  e906801932ac  sh
```

and I check `127.0.0.1:8000`, here is the response:

```
/app # wget localhost:8000

Connecting to localhost:8000 (127.0.0.1:8000)
saving to 'index.html'
index.html           100% |*****************************************************************************************************************************| 10697  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved
```

but when I try this in my local machine, the response is different.

```
wget localhost:8000   
--2022-04-23 18:48:06--  http://localhost:8000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2022-04-23 18:48:07--  (try: 2)  http://localhost:8000/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2022-04-23 18:48:09--  (try: 3)  http://localhost:8000/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2022-04-23 18:48:12--  (try: 4)  http://localhost:8000/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2022-04-23 18:48:16--  (try: 5)  http://localhost:8000/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

---

when I try `docker ps` here is the response:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES

e906801932ac   dj-test   "python manage.py ru…"   29 minutes ago   Up 29 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   nice_goldwasser
```

Can you help me to find the problem here?
Thanks.

Comment: you probably dont bind the public network interface.

Comment: Did you start the container on your local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `"8000"` instead  `"0.0.0.0:8000"` in the CMD command.

see more:

[django change default runserver port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639085/django-change-default-runserver-port)

Comment: maybe you should flag it as duplicate instead of answering.