# how can I change django application server port number in spyne

Tags: django, soap, spyne

I am trying to run the spyne Django soap server project on my computer but I can't run the project because the default port number which is 8000, is already in use so I want to change the port number of django soap server.

[the related project](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/tree/master/examples/django)

the related code:

```
    class Attributes(DjangoComplexModel.Attributes):
        django_model = FieldContainer
        django_exclude = ['excluded_field']


class HelloWorldService(Service):
    @rpc(Unicode, Integer, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
    def say_hello(ctx, name, times):
        for i in range(times):
            yield 'Hello, %s' % name


class ContainerService(Service):
    @rpc(Integer, _returns=Container)
    def get_container(ctx, pk):
        try:
            return FieldContainer.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except FieldContainer.DoesNotExist:
            raise ResourceNotFoundError('Container')

    @rpc(Container, _returns=Container)
    def create_container(ctx, container):
        try:
            return FieldContainer.objects.create(**container.as_dict())
        except IntegrityError:
            raise ResourceAlreadyExistsError('Container')

class ExceptionHandlingService(DjangoService):

    """Service for testing exception handling."""

    @rpc(_returns=Container)
    def raise_does_not_exist(ctx):
        return FieldContainer.objects.get(pk=-1)

    @rpc(_returns=Container)
    def raise_validation_error(ctx):
        raise ValidationError(None, 'Invalid.')


app = Application([HelloWorldService, ContainerService,
                   ExceptionHandlingService],
    'spyne.examples.django',
    in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
    out_protocol=Soap11(),
)

hello_world_service = csrf_exempt(DjangoApplication(app))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django change default runserver port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639085/django-change-default-runserver-port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way out there is just type the required port to run after the "runserver" command so:

```
python manage.py runserver 7000
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the django app specify the port like this `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080` to use 8080 instead of 8000