# How to run Django server on device IP address?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I run Django server using this,

```
python manage.py runserver ip-addr:8000
```

I can see the server is running in the terminal. But when I open the browser, the **This site can't be reached** message is displayed. There is no error I see in the terminal or the console.

Also, everything works perfectly fine with 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 but not with my ip-addr.

How can I run or know that if there is something wrong or any problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [manage.py runserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768797/manage-py-runserver)

Comment: Have you set your IP in ALLOWED_HOSTS?

Comment: By ip-addr, do you mean your public ip address? And why do you want to run it with your public IP address? Is it because you want it to be accessible by whole world?

Comment: sometimes firewall blocks requests to your server on a specific port .
Can you open the port and try again? make sure to close it after your tests are done.

Comment: I'm trying to connect Django (API) to react native which works well on the web browser but it doesn't work when I use it on the phone.

Comment: Yes, I have added all the IP in ALLLOWED_HOSTS